# findByIdの競合？？ Spring Boot Maven installエラー

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

Spring Boot入門という書籍のとおりコードを打っているのですが、エラーになり、どうすればいいかわからず困っています。どうかお助けください。

↓ファイルのエラー

```
package com.kuwa.springboot.repositories;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.kuwa.springboot.MyData;

@Repository 
public interface MyDataRepository extends JpaRepository<MyData, Long> {

    public MyData findById(Long name);

}
```

上記の「public MyData findById(Long name);」のMyDataに対して以下のエラー
    ”この行に複数マーカーがあります
        - 戻りの型は CrudRepository.findById(Long) と互換性がありません
        - Parameter type (Long) does not match domain class property definition (long).
        - org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository.findById 
         を実装します”

↓Maven Install時のエラー

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building MyBootApp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:resources (default-resources) @ MyBootApp ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 5 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ MyBootApp ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 4 source files to C:\Users\yoshi\Documents\workspace-sts-3.9.2.RELEASE\MyBootApp\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/Users/yoshi/Documents/workspace-sts-3.9.2.RELEASE/MyBootApp/src/main/java/com/kuwa/springboot/repositories/MyDataRepository.java:[12,23] com.kuwa.springboot.repositories.MyDataRepositoryのfindById(java.lang.Long)はorg.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepositoryのfindById(ID)と競合します
  戻り値の型com.kuwa.springboot.MyDataはjava.util.Optional<com.kuwa.springboot.MyData>と互換性がありません
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 12.430 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-07-22T23:44:37+09:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 29M/211M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The requested profile "pom.xml" could not be activated because it does not exist.
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project MyBootApp: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /C:/Users/yoshi/Documents/workspace-sts-3.9.2.RELEASE/MyBootApp/src/main/java/com/kuwa/springboot/repositories/MyDataRepository.java:[12,23] com.kuwa.springboot.repositories.MyDataRepositoryのfindById(java.lang.Long)はorg.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepositoryのfindById(ID)と競合します
[ERROR] 戻り値の型com.kuwa.springboot.MyDataはjava.util.Optional<com.kuwa.springboot.MyData>と互換性がありません
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

findById methodはCrudRepository (JpaRepositoryのimplementしているクラス)ですでに定義されており、メソッドシグネチャは以下です。

```
Optional<T> findById(ID var1);
```

これに対し、同じ名前で戻り値が違うメソッドを定義したため、エラーとなっています。
Optionalの戻り値で良い場合はfindByIdメソッドは定義しなくてもいいので、それで試してみてください。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございました。他の方も同じ教材を使い躓いていたようで、以下のブログを参考に直しました。結論、「public Optional<MyData> findById(Long name);」に修正することになりました。http://blog.livedoor.jp/enmatome/archives/8687984.html